# Why doesn't exist .MergeShape method in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I tried to combine/intersect two shapes with a VBA code to create a custom shape but it didn't work. My system (Office professional plus 2010) tells me that this method (.MergeShape) doesn't exist. But in different posts this method is used and documented by Microsoft. Is my Powerpoint version too old or do I need to add an additional library (and which one)? Or can I do this operation (combine/intersect etc.) in a better way with another VBA method?

Help is appreciated!
Wosl

Comment: PowerPoint 2010 doesn't have the ability to merge shapes either in the program interface or in VBA. You'll have to upgrade to be able to do that.

Comment: John, Powerpoint 2010 does support the feature to create a custom shape (through combine, intersect, merge, subtract) from two selected shapes. It did it many times. It works through the user interface (menu "Start" ...) but I don't know how to do the same operation via VBA. Therefore, my thought was, the method .MergeShape will do this job.

Comment: The 2010 Merge Shapes command was present in the user interface only if you customize the Ribbon. It wasn't added to the object model at that time and is not available in VBA. As I stated before, you'll have to upgrade to be able to do that. I'm not here to argue, just to present the facts.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been my expectation that the feature is available in the user interface but has not been implemented in VBA for Powerpoint 2010. You are right, I need to upgrade to a newer PPT version.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Is there any way to acchieve something similar using `BuildFreeform`/`FreeformBuilder`?